# resharper wraps Html helper (@html.)in Razor files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, resharper

I have a Razor files (.cshtml) that contains only Html helpers objects, like this:

```
@Html.BeginTableHeader(
Html.OverviewHeader(property: "state", width: "78px", cssClass: "public light-grey"), 
Html.OverviewHeader("Title", "title", "", "light-grey"), 
Html.OverviewHeader("Name", "name", "", "light-grey"))

@Html.BeginTableBody(
       Html.OverviewBodyText("title"), Html.OverviewBodyText("name"))
```

when I try to apply some formating style to the code, all Htmlhelpers will wrap to a single line

```
 @Html.BeginTableHeader(Html.OverviewHeader(property: "state", width:"78px",cssClass: "public light-grey"), Html.OverviewHeader("Title", "title", "", "light-grey"), Html.OverviewHeader("Name", "name", "", "light-grey"))
@Html.BeginTableBody(Html.OverviewBodyText("title"),Html.OverviewBodyText("name"))
```

how can I avoid this?
in Resharper as I undrestood formatting features for Razor files just adjust IN the editors, this change is happend when I define some formating style for C#.

Comment: Got the same with methods chain. Did you happen to find out a solution?